# Getting location from a middle-website redirect

Tags: javascript, redirect, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm looking for a good method to get the location from user entering my website from a QR code.

**1.** An user uses my qr code and goes to mywebsite.com/qrcode

**2.** mywebsite.com/qrcode has a javascript redirecto to -> typeform.com/mysurvey

I have GA and GTM installed and settled. What I want is to gather info from the users that 'passed through' mywebsite.com/qrcode.

What I've tried is to just put a redirect but GA doesn't seem to 'save' the data since its just a redirect. I'm not an expert tho.

Can you guys give me some tips on how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom event in GTM. Trigger the event before the redirect JS runs on (mywebsite.com/qrcode) page. Next, connect the custom event to the Tag which tracks the QR code view.

The Gotcha here is that you will need to make sure the Analytics API is completed before the redirect happens else the redirect might cancel the API request.